# Skip integration tests in maven by directory

Tags: java, maven

Our project structure looks something like this (sorry about the formatting):

```
server/
       pom.xml
       src/
           main/
                java/
           test/
                java/
           it/
                java/
```

I would like `mvn clean test` to skip all the tests in it/java *regardless* of the name of the test. The solutions I have seen depend on integration tests being in a different package or having some prefix on the name to indicate that they are integration tests.

Is there a way to exclude it/java from running when I run `mvn clean test`? Eventually we want to be able to run the integration tests with by running mvn integration-test.

Comment: Why not keep them in /test/java/it? Shouldn't you be able to skip them? Maven layout says that test goes in /test/java

Comment: @XtremeBiker I didn't want to have to put them in a separate package if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is probably to make it a multi-module project, and then in the it module skip tests based on different maven properties.  This would allow you the flexibility that you're looking for.

Comment: Is there no way for the unit tests and integration tests to live together in the same module?

Comment: Absolutely that's valid to have them live together in the same module.  You'd need to more tightly control the phase the tests execute then.  You're running 'mvn test' and it's triggering your integration tests, which would imply that they're running in the test phase, no the integration-test phase of the [maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).  You need to change those tests to run at the correct lifecycle.  It's just often easier to use modules to keep your integration tests separate and have greater control.

Comment: That's the purpose of my original question. I don't understand how to do that. I need to change them to run at the integration-test phase _and not_ at the test phase.

Comment: Sorry, see my comment above (edited), accidentally hit enter ;)

Comment: Also, this is a good article for you: http://www.agile-engineering.net/2011/06/seperating-maven-unit-integration-tests.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think src/it/java is a folder known to maven so if you put your tests in there they will be ignored simply because its a random folder to maven? :)

Anyway. To execute integration tests I recommend using the maven-failsafe-plugin which was build for this: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/
It does also rely on some naming convention to distinguish integration tests from standard ones but I could re-configure the testSourceDirectory. But I think the classes may need to be compiled first if you change that folder (but that should be possible).

The unit tests are then configured to be executed by the maven-surefire-plugin.

What I usually to is have the surefire-plugin execute all tests but exclude the IntegrationTests (using a pattern in the configuration) and the failsafe-plugin include those but exclude the standard tests. But I have the tests named differently so I can use the conventions for the folders.

Comment: Indeed, src/it/java is added as a test source during the generate-test-sources phase. I was hoping to avoid having to rename all my tests to follow a pattern that distinguishes them, but it's starting to look as though that's the best option.

Comment: If those classes are generated than the 'src/it/java' is the wrong place. They should be placed into 'target/generated-source/WhatEver' cause every generate would change checked in files (VCS!). Apart from that the tool which generates the classes should also add the generated folder to the compile sources which will handle the thing maven-compiler-plugin will compile also those generated classes.